# How to complete a span

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Hey I have a simple question.

Say I have vector space V (dimV > 1).
B = Span{v1,v2} and C = span{u1}.
I have to find a vector u2 such that span{u1,u2} = span{v1,v2} = B.

How do I do it ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always possible. For instance, take $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now say I take $B = \text{span}(e_1, e_2)$ and $C = \text{span}(e_3)$. Then $C$ contains $e_3$ while $B$ does not. Hence there is no vector $u_2$ such that $\text{span}(e_3, u_2) = B$.

If you know that $u_1$ is in $B$, however, and $u_1$ is nonzero, then either $\text{span}(u_1) = B$ already, or any $u_2 \in B \setminus \text{span}(u_1)$ will satisfy $\text{span}(u_1, u_2) = \text{span}(v_1, v_2)$.

Comment: Yeah I know, in this case V=R^3. B=span{v1,v2} and C=span{u1}, so it's possible. How do I find that u2 ? (v1 and v2 are linearly independent)

Comment: Again, not always possible unless you know that $u_1$ is in $B$ to begin with. In that case, refer to what I wrote above.

Comment: In this case u1 is indeed in B. But I still don't get it how do I find u2∈B∖span(u1)? or even B∖span(u1)?

Comment: If $u_1 \notin \text{span}(v_1)$ then we could use $u_2 = v_1$. Otherwise we can use $u_2 = v_2$ since $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent. In general, finding something in $B \setminus \text{span}(u_1)$ should be easy

Comment: Oh right. I feel so dumb right now, srry. thanks ;)